# Feature extraction of image by ORB

Tags: python, computer-vision

I want to extract features of text in an image , 
I applied otsu thresholding , followed by erosion ,dilation , found contours and drew them

In the end I used ORB algortithm on preprocessed image

```
def ORB_descp(ppi):
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    kp = orb.detect(ppi,None)
    kp, des = orb.compute(ppi, kp)
    return cv2.drawKeypoints(ppi,kp,None,color=(0,255,0), flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS),kp,des
```

now i printed des in above code and i got a 2D array where each array within 2D array contains 32 integer something like that

```
des= [ [180 246 202  86 211 123 167 253 114 159 100 222  64 224 239 159  57 206
130 186 113 247 188 106  56   7 101  45 233 121 238 176] ,................
..,[189 127  34  83 211 191 182 220  55 110 125 255  74 245 239 156  61 250
135 246 254 182  56  62 123 205  37 231 251 247 238 215] ]
```

What is this array of des,are they features of image ?
 If they are how can I use them for text recognition and if not how can I extract feature of text in image for text recognition .
I have to use these features to train SVM , but I am struck at this point
I am not able to extract features.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You want to extract features in text and do what ?

Comment: I want extract the features of text in an image , make a list of featurres and train SVM for text detection in images

Comment: @ArshadAhmad did you figure it out? i have the same issue